# Как записать в файл вещественное число с точкой вместо запятой?

Tags: format, консоль, файлы, c++, printf

Покажите, пожалуйста, как для функции fprintf задать форматирование так, чтобы она double  писала в файл не через "," а через ".". Если в fprintf этого никак не сделать, то, может быть, как-то у cout это можно сделать?

Comment: Дело в локали, беглый гуглеж подсказал мне делать так:

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "C");

Возможно, использовать "C" не очень правильно, но это точно сработало на локалке (строго говоря. у меня запятую начало писать только с `ru_RU.UTF8`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Действительно, все дело в локали, как и сказал [@Etki](/users/16095/etki).

Возможно, для Вашей цели достаточно установить `LC_NUMERIC` в "C", а остальные категории оставить без изменения.

Вот пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  double d = 10.1;
  char *loc = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

  printf("DEFAULT LOCALE  %s\nd = %f\n", loc, d);
  loc = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "ru_RU.utf8");
  printf("%s: d = %f\n", loc, d);
  loc = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");
  printf("%s: d = %f\n", loc, d);

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc c.c
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
DEFAULT LOCALE  LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_TIME=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_NAME=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_ADDRESS=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_TELEPHONE=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_SG.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_SG.UTF-8
d = 10.100000
ru_RU.utf8: d = 10,100000
C: d = 10.100000
End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает